# How to consolidate object file content in an archive?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries

I compile several (hundreds) C++ files into object files and then `ar` them into an archive. I notice each object file is quite large, presumably from each including a rich set of headers. The set is mostly the same across objects. The archive size is the sum of it's parts, and it's reaching for GB size which is ridiculous IMO.

Assuming object file content is mostly repetition of what is found in the shared headers, how can I reduce the size of the archive? Preferably in a way that doesn't involve full rewrite of code or build system.

---

I compared the size of one such object file with and without debug information (`objcopy --strip-debug foo.o foo_no_debug.o`) and discovered that for one file 99.5% of the content is debug information. Might be relevant for any answers. I guess the workaround is being more restrictive with debug info flag(s).

Answer (score 0):

Some searching and experimenting I've found my answer.

Short version: `ld` option `--relocatable`,`-r`, sometimes called "incremental linking":

```
ld -r -o abc.o a.o b.o c.o
```

Long version:

`ld` CAN do it, but is REALLY BAD at it.

Incrementally linking together 10 identical files including headers, compiled with `-g3` option, only reduced size of archive from 24MB to 16MB. Even worse is `ld` does not support compression, meaning any compressed debug information (compiled with `-gz`) is decompressed by incremental linking!

Thankfully, `ld.gold` performs much better, resulting in a 5MB archive. `ld.gold` also has options for compressing output, `-O6` and `--compress-debug-sections=zlib`, lowering archive size down to 3MB.

Headers used when testing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/memory_order.hpp>
#include <boost/token_functions.hpp>
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>
#include <boost/concept_archetype.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Tested using GCC 6.3.0, GNU ld 2.28, and GNU gold 1.14. Didn't test LLVM `lld`, but since supporting the same options and being top notch overall I'd expect similar results.